# SQL query to find matching records but with differences in case sensitivity?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to generate a simple query to find all records in the database (case sensitive), that have an match, but not in the same case.

An example of what I'm trying to find are all instances of the below:

```
dog
DOG
Dog
```

Is there any such functionality in SQL to create such a query or if anyone has anything on hand would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a case insensitive collation.

Comment: What's the specific database engine? Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something using lower()/upper() function like below

```
select * from tablename
where lower(columnname)=lower('dog')
```

OR

```
select * from tablename
    where upper(columnname)=upper('dog')
```